# How to 'UnJustify!' text in GNU nano

Tags: editors, nano

I enjoy using `nano` as a respite from my usual GTK-based text editor. I like the simplicity of the interface, and using CTRL-K is the fastest way I know of to edit down long textfiles.

However, I have one major gripe: whenever I justify text using CTRL-J, the editor prints the smug little message `Can now UnJustify!` -- yet I have not been able to find a way to unjustify text. Pressing M-U (which a Google search could reveal, M-U not being mentioned at all in the program's help files) simply seems to cause a glitch. The keyboard becomes unresponsive. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> immediately after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, the justification is undone. Nano in fact tells you (the `^U` shortcut description at the bottom changes from `UnCut Text` to `UnJustify`). No, I won't blame you for not noticing that. You can't unjustify if you've typed anything after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Yes, that's pretty underwhelming (far from a general undo).

Comment: Nano 2.4 + now has undo support enabled. ALT+U and ALT+E are undo and redo respectively.